# Front camera error with getUsermedia() Error: "Notreadableerror: could not start video source"

Tags: javascript, android-camera

In my html code i have 3 video labels , in desktop the videos work fine but when i try in mobile, only works the two first cameras, when i specify the "user" camera in the last one jumps the next error in android "Notreadableerror: could not start video source".

```
function enableCam() {

video = document.getElementById('video');
// Get access to the camera!
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {

    var constraints;
    var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    if (isMobile) {
        constraints = {video: {width: {
            exact: 256
        },
        height: {
            exact: 192
        }, facingMode: "user"}};

    }else {
       constraints = {video: {width: {
           exact: 256
       },
       height: {
           exact: 192
       }, facingMode: "environment"}};
    }

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {

        readFile(video,stream);//This method plays the video and save the image
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Do you know what type of camera it is? Could it be an infrared camera or any other source that doesn't have a video feed? This was a problem with my Windows laptop, where it tried to get a video source from my Windows Hello infrared source, which isn't possible.

Comment: In windows the cameras works fine, the problem is when i try to enable the front camera in movile devises

Answer (score 4):

This error will occur on iOS 13.3 if getUserMedia gets run too much. 13.4 fixes it.

Also, stopping previous streams might be helpful before running getUserMedia again.

ie) Since you are running getUserMedia twice in a row, perhaps capturing the stream the first time, stopping it, and then running the second getUserMedia with a setTimeout delay might help unblock things.

The constraints might also be an issue: passing an empty constraint "{}" might help. Passing "{audio:true,video:true}" might help also.

Trying a different browser might help too; chrome, firefox, Safari, and even Opera.

I have a mobile web-app that is open-source that makes use of smartphone cameras. I've had to account for a lot of particularities of different browsers, cameras, phones, and constraints. The code might come in handy if you get stuck again: https://github.com/steveseguin/obsninja

Answer (score 0):

Did you gave permissions?

config.xml

```
<platform name="ios">
 ...
 <custom-config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
   <string>Access to camera to make video calls.</string>
 </custom-config-file>
 <custom-config-file parent="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
   <string>Access to microphone to make calls.</string>
 </custom-config-file>
</platform>
```

And the following for Android:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<platform name="android">
 ...
 <custom-preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
 <custom-preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
 <custom-config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
 </custom-config-file>
</platform>
```

From

https://developers.connectycube.com/cordova/code-samples-videochat-cordova

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue with the latest chrome / webview update. I was used to pass the deviceId from  enumerateDevices to getUserMedia as option. This caused the "Notreadableerror: could not start video source" error for me on some endpoints as the deviceId on latest chrome version seems to change with every request and was therefore invalid at the time i tried to start the camera.

```
{
     'deviceId': {'exact':device.deviceId}, 
     'facingMode': 'environment',
     'video': { 'width': this.width, 'height': this.height }
}
```

I changed my code to

```
{
      'facingMode':  'environment',
      'video': { 'width': this.width, 'height': this.height }
}
```

which fixed the issue for me.